# Error when trying to see mvn version in cmd

Tags: maven

I keep getting this error when trying to enter "mvn -version in the cmd.

```
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/c
     lassworlds/launcher/Launcher
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.lau
     ncher.Launcher
     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
     Could not find the main class: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
```

.         Program will exit.
          'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: I've seen problems like this when my Java installation was partially corrupted. Do you see similar issues with `java -version` or `javac -version`?

Comment: C:\Users\user>javac -version
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. This is what i get when i try to enter java or javac -version

Comment: That just means that either `javac` isn't in your path, or you don't have a JDK installed. What about `java -version`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is usually a problem with misconfiguring M2_HOME or M3_HOME.  I'm not sure, but I think you can't have both set.  Also, do a "which mvn" - apparently some JVM installs will install a mvn in usr/bin.

Comment: I dont have M2_HOME set in my path. What should the variable be in the user variable path or system variable path?

Comment: Ok then, you shouldn't need either M2_HOME or M3_HOME - as long as you're running the right mvn.bat.  Do a "which" on it to be sure.

Comment: what do you mean a "which" on it? and how do i run the mvn.bat? They make this sooooo complicated.

Comment: When you type "mvn", what program is it running, and where does it come from?  "which" is a Unix/Cygwin command that will tell you that.  If you want to use some other means to figure it out, do so.  Did you put the Maven bin dir on your path?  If not, do so.  Make sure it's near the front.

Comment: I put it in my path. and im using neither cygwin nor Unix? WOuld these be easier on  ubuntu?

Comment: I think you're missing the point.  There is a good chance that another mvn is running and being confused with the one you want.  You need to determine whether this is true.  "which" happens to be a tool to do this.  There are others.  For instance, if you remove Maven from your path, and type mvn, what happens?  Or, much slower, search your disk for mvn.*.  Given the problems, I'd set M2_HOME as described in the "Windows 2000/XP" section [here](http://maven.apache.org/download.html).  Use the rest of the instructions there as well.

Answer (score 2):

your maven configure is the problem.

once check your system variables path, MAVEN_HOME AND JAVA_HOME.

IN PATH - %MVN_HOME%/bin and that maven bin path also add in that path.

IN MAVEN_HOME - where your placing the Maven folder that path you add only not bin or lib folders.

IN JAVA_HOME - where you are installed java software that path can place in that directory. This is also not lib or bin folders just only JDK path.

In classpath- you can add just normally lib folder of the maven.

If you are not added the java_home your adding only maven_home that is also some will be raised.

Here i am placing some site url see that one solve your problem.

http://horrikhalid.wordpress.com/2011/01/12/a-simple-tutorial-of-jsf-2-0-eclipse-weld-and-maven-2/

N.S.Reddy

Comment: Changed my path from the full text string to the alias, and it fixed this issue for me, Thank you very much.