# Maven Error when running mvn -version

Tags: maven

I got following error while running `mvn -version` command in mac.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
```

Please give suggestion to solve this error.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this question, it should provide you with the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/11118237/1570834

Comment: which maven version are you using?