# Maven not getting installed

Tags: maven, redhat

I have installed maven in RedHat

by

```
curl http://www.jpackage.org/jpackage50.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/jpackage.repo
```

```
yum install maven2
```

and when i hit

```
mvn --version
```

getting this error

---

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118237/maven-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-codehaus-plexus-classworlds-l

Comment: Don't install Maven 2 anymore http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html Download maven from http://maven.apache.org/download.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across similar problem and after adding below environment variables it worked for me

```
export M2_HOME=<your apache-maven installation path up to bin>
export JAVA_HOME=<your Java installation path up to bin>
```

Also modify your PATH variable

Comment: M2_HOME is not neccessary. Only the bin folder of the appropriate maven installation (something/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin) must be in the path.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing that you can copy maven source and point M2_HOME to that location.

Comment: Why using the maven source? Use the binary distributions instead.