# Maven:Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher

Tags: maven

Same to this one but still didn't figure out. tried all solution....

[Maven error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118237/maven-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-codehaus-plexus-classworlds-l)

OS: Windows 7
Installed Maven 3.3.3 from ftp://mirror.reverse.net/pub/apache/maven/maven-3/3.3.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.3-bin.zip

Environment variable:

```
Path = C:\Tools\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin

M2_HOME = C:\Tools\apache-maven-3.3.3
```

**Error:**

> $ mvn
>
> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launche r.Launcher

Comment: It is not required anymore to set M2_HOME, actually it is better to remove it. When working with multiple Maven versions this can cause the mentioned issue.

Comment: It turns out the downloaded package is not complete. Or files are missing during extraction process.

Answer (score 5):

I guess this error caused because of downloading SRC instead of BINARY from Maven site. Please make sure to download Binary zip.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the error by downloading the bin file from maven, not the src file, and then the path pointing to the bin directory

Answer (score 1):

Step1: Install ApacheMaven Binary-tar.gz archive file
Step2: Add C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin to the PATH under user variables
Step3: In command prompt, run mvn -v

Answer (score 0):

Change M2_HOME by MAVEN_HOME. It worked for me on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed mine, taken from

[use M3 home](http://www.johnlabarge.com/post/33156663109/dreaded-maven-error-could-not-find-or-load-main)

I had this little issue on my Mac after installing maven3 and jdk1.7.  Here is what fixed my issue:

1. Remove the M2_HOME variable from the path.
2. Add M3_HOME variable with the path to your maven 3 installation.

Here is the interesting part: I use symbolic links for versioning.  The values of both M2_HOME and M3_HOME were identical.  Both were /Developer/maven.  Hence it appears that the name M2_HOME in place of M3_HOME is what actually causes the issue.  I leave it as an exercise (that I may return to) to find the issue in the source.

Answer (score 0):

This means maven is not properly configured.

There is a chance that you might have downloaded wrong zip file or incomplete file.

Once you are sure the file is correct and unzipped, in windows, go to command prompt,go to bin,and try to execute the mvn.bat file. The error originates from that file.If it is executing nothing to worry.

Avoid setting MAVEN_HOME.Its not needed. Set the maven bin only in the PATH

Answer (score 0):

Remove & disable the `M2_HOME` in the /etc/environment using the `unset` function as in

```
unset M2_HOME
```