# Error while using mvn -v in CMD after setting up Maven binaries on Windows

Tags: java, maven

I have installed the Maven `apache-maven-3.3.9` binaries  on Windows 10 and have set below variable as :

```
M2_HOME: 
C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9

M2: %M2_HOME%\bin

MAVEN_OPTS: Xms256m -Xmx512m

PATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin;%M2%
```

But when I run `mvn -v` in CMD, I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Xms256m
```

I have already tried solution listed on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118237/maven-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-codehaus-plexus-classworlds-l)

Comment: in the `MAVEN_OPTS` here above, did you miss an initial `-` while typing the question or effectively in your system?

Answer (score 1):

You have invalid environment variable `MAVEN_OPTS` (missing dash). It should be

```
-Xmx256m -Xmx512m
```

Comment: Thanks Man! It was silly mistake. It worked when corrected  MAVEN_OPTS i.e. -Xms256m -Xmx512m