# Issues with instaling apache maven

Tags: java, apache, maven, maven-3, system-variable

I have so many problems with installing apache maven. I have tried lot of instructions from youtube and from StackOverflow as well but none of these solutions is the right one. So in system variables I have the following

```
JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111

M2
%M2_HOME%\bin

M2_HOME
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.3.9

Path
%M2%
```

If I type in command line `javac` it's working fine, but when I type `mvn --version` I have an error

> "Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher"

Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: You probably need quotes around your `M2_HOME` variable... But you do not need that environment variable to begin with, just set the `PATH` to the correct value.

Comment: I've deleted M2 variable and in Path variable I have changed to %M2_HOME%\bin but still same.

Comment: Did you add the quotes? You should just have `PATH` contain `"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin"` without any `M2` or `M2_HOME` and with quotes.

Comment: Yep with quotes I'm getting error message from command line "Files\Apache was unexpected at this time." Withouth M2 and M2_Home is same :(

Comment: read the maven start script *mvn.cmd* under *bin* and locate where the problem turn up.

Comment: Did you look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118237/maven-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-codehaus-plexus-classworlds-l)? It seems very similar to yours.

Comment: @31piy thanks for link, I've found solution from this link. So solution here was to download and unpackage file apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.tar.gz, rather than apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.zip as proposed from offical instructions. Cheers!

Comment: by the way, your question title is pretty vague

Answer (score 0):

My fix for "Files\Apache was unexpected at this time." was to remove the quotes around the path when setting `JAVA_HOME`. 
Just run: `set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111`, no quotes.