# Maven Error "cant find or load main class..."

Tags: maven, homebrew

Full error code:

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher

This is the error I get when I try and do any mvn command after I installed maven using homebrew. I think the error may have to do with symlinks not being created properly since when I run:

```
which mvn
```

my result is:

```
/usr/local/bin/mvn
```

also when I run:

```
echo $M@2_HOME
```

I get:

```
/Users/USERNAME/apache-maven-3.3.9
```

which doesn't even seem to exist in my system. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118237/maven-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-codehaus-plexus-classworlds-l

Comment: @AdamSmith funny enough, I tried only more complex solutions but it seems unset M2_HOME was all I needed. Thank you.

Comment: Cool :) no worries

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118237/maven-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-codehaus-plexus-classworlds-l)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying more complex solutions @Pete in the first comment on the main post had my try

```
unset M2_HOME
```

and that did the trick.

Comment: Thanks saved me after 30 min+ loss! Damn!