# Jenkins maven error while building job

Tags: maven, jenkins, execution

I am running the following maven command from my jenkins box -

`+ /temp/app/tools/apache-maven-3.0.4/bin/mvn --update-snapshots clean deploy`

But this is throwing the following error -

`Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher`

Any clue why I am getting this error? The maven installation seems OK (as I have triggered mvn command directly from the Linux server).

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118237/maven-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-codehaus-plexus-classworlds-l ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the `.bashrc` file to set the Maven home, sourced it and then restarted the Jenkins server. That seemed to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your maven installation. The version must match and set your Maven_Home or M3_HOME variable